# Join mysql with null value

Tags: mysql, join

I have sample data in the following table on MySQL:

```
Id          value       Source
=====       ===         ====
2           24          F
2           20          M
2           10          F
```

And I want to join with this table

```
Id          value       Source
=====       ===         ====
2           2           T
2           5           T
```

and the result I want be like this:

```
Id          value       value       Source      Source
=====       ===         ====        ====        ====
2           24          2           F           T
2           20          5           M           T
2           10          null        F           null
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`:

Comment: `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id`

Comment: I have edit my question, can you help me?

Comment: Both my comment and the two responses below answer your question.

Comment: You should specify a criteria to let us understand how obtain your expected result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.id,
       table1.value,
       table2.value,
       table1.source,
       table2.source
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

use left join

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below schema to create two SQL tables and then add the data as given above in the two respective table T1 & T2.

After that execute the below given SQL JOIN command to get the desired output:

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[T1] ******/

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[T2]******/

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

/****** SQL JOIN ******/

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.Value,T2.Value,T1.Source,T2.Source
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID;
```

---